# How would you say "I eat rice in china" vs "I'm in china and eat rice" in mandarin?

Tags: translation

how would you say in mandarin
I eat rice in china
vs
I'm in china and eat rice
they have slightly different meanings

Comment: What is the difference between the two? Is it just that you put an emphasis on different subjects?

Comment: @Wolfking that's a good point. "I'm in China and eat rice" isn't the sort of thing I can imagine a native English speaker saying. "I'm in China and I eat rice" is possible - as an answer to the questions "Are you in China? Do you eat rice?" (="Are you in China at the moment? Do you eat rice in general?". // "I eat rice in China" is fine, eg as an answer to "What do you eat in China" (="When you're in China, what do you eat"). Thomas I would suggest changing your second sentence with "I'm in China and I eat rice" .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eat rice in China.

我在中国吃米饭。

I eat rice when I am in China.

我在中国的时候吃米饭。

I am in China and I eat rice.

我现在在中国，我吃米饭。

I am in China and I am eating rice (now).

我现在在中国，我正在吃米饭。

// I'm no expert but the English word "and" can link more grammatical structures than Chinese does. I feel this example would be broken down into 2 unique statements. You wouldn't use 和 in this situation anyway. If I'm not mistaken, 和 can link nouns 我和你 and adjectives 大和小, but not verbs 是和吃。

Answer (score 0):

short answer:
I eat rice in China: 在中国我吃米饭。
I'm in China and eat rice： 我在中国吃米饭。